# Mac Mini late 2012 second monitor resolution

Tags: display, mac-mini, resolution

I have a dual monitor setup for mac mini 2012, 2 x lg flatron w2243 one is connected through dvi to hdmi adapter and works fine at a 1920x1080 resolution, the other has a vga to mini display (thunderbolt) connection, but the highest resolution it works at is the 1280x720 and I want them both at 1920x1080.

As soon as I increase the resolution on the second monitor, the monitor goes black and occasionally flickers.

As for vga to thunderbolt adapter, it works fine as i've tested the same monitor with my MacBook Pro 13" Retina and it's working great at a 1920x1080 res.

Let me know if you have any ideas or if you need any more info.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-late-2012-specs.html) on EveryMac.com the resolutions you want to run should be supported.

The problem might be the adaptor.

I would try a PRAM reset (restart while holding down `Command`-`Option`-`P`-`R`), or possibly an SMC reset, detailed in [Apple's Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) system.

If these don't work, I'd try a different adaptor.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Mark, in the end I bought a genuine apple adapter from the apple store and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem getting a new Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter.